# Calling and using the result of a function inside another function (Python)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I *think* I'm just unaware of some basic syntax here.

The following code gives an error "global name 'adder' is not defined".

```
def math(a, b):
    adder = a + b
    return adder

def usesmath(x, y):
    math(6, 4)
    subtractor = adder - (x + y)
    print subtractor

usesmath(3, 2)
```

Clearly, this doesn't work because the variable 'adder' does not exist within usesmath(); how can I make the variable be recognised?

Comment: `adder = math(6, 4)`. This is not basic syntax, it's basic semantics: a function returns a value *without a name*.

Comment: You need to learn what [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science%29) is.

Comment: @user3599580 First, do not use tabs in your code, use spaces. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans! What if math() returned a tuple?

Comment: you can use `subtractor = math(6, 4) - (x + y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this inside usesmath: `adder = math(6, 4)`

Comment: @Sergio Martinez Will do - it says I have to wait 10 min.

Comment: @user3599580 okay sorry for that :)

Comment: @user3599580 If math() returned a tuple, `adder` would get assigned to the tuple. I have a feeling you're trying to get at something specific with that question, but I'm not sure what it is.